# PHP-FPM Wordpress Debug

Tags: debug, wp-debug

Is there any way to get WP_DEBUG to log errors when running PHP-FPM?

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );
```